# Ubuntu bluetooth audio, no sound after pairing

Tags: sound, bluetooth, gstreamer

I've rarely used bluetooth on Kubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to use a set of Bluetooth speakers (Loewe Speaker 2go). I've done the pairing with the wizard, and the device shows as an "Audio Sink", whatever that is. But no sound comes out.
In the [Audio Setup], [Device preference] doesn't show that device, neither does the [Audio Hardware setup].
The backend is GStreamer.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You may need pulseaudio `module-bluetooth-discover`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/414258/successfully-connected-to-a-bluetooth-speaker-but-how-do-i-direct-sound-there

Comment: Thanks to "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover" I now see it in Device Preference and Audio Hardware Setup, but no sound, and the I only see the [Mono] button even when Profile is A2DP... I won't have time to work on this for the next week...

Comment: You will have more options to change profiles/device setup by installing and running **pavucontrol**.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but only after a reboot.