# Bluetooth speakers in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I have successfully paired Microboom bluetooth speaker to Ubuntu Laptop, using Blueman 1.23. However, even when connection is ON, I do not see the Microboom speaker in Sound settings to direct audio output to that.

Comment: Blueman is not the default software for the Ubuntu desktop. Please use the default bluetooth application. That should work better in conjunction with the default sound settings application.

Comment: What is the native bluetooth app called?

Comment: You should just use it through the indicator or system settings when using Unity. The connection wizard is named `bluetooth-wizard` though.

Comment: Thru Launcher I see both "Bluetooth" ,and "Bluetooth Manager". I quit Blueman & set up thru Bluetooth..still no luck.

Comment: Found solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/414258/successfully-connected-to-a-bluetooth-speaker-but-how-do-i-direct-sound-there?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

blueman and pulseaudio do not play well together in Ubuntu 14.04. If you want to use it, try the [utopic's blueman package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/blueman) which has a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful installing MagicBox on Ubuntu 14.04
after I removed blueman and followed these steps:

- I turned on MagicBox and selected BlueTooth Setting
- clicked on MagicBox II (which had not been displayed prior to removing blueman
- selected Headset MagicBoxII and then sound settings
- choose the mode: (option)High Fidelity(AZDP).
- I tested sound and all worked well.  Finally I reinstalled Blueman, restarted and allowed me to improve the quality of using my headset directly in my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install "MagicBox". (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)