# Bluetooth Headphones Establish Connection But Isn't Listed in Audio Devices

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I know there is a temporary solution but I can no longer find it.

I've successfully paired my bluetooth headset/earbuds to my computer which is running Ubuntu 14.04, but it does not show up in the Audio Devices list.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem, or some way to fix this?

Comment: Change the default sound device in your audio devices to the bluetooth headset/earbuds.

Comment: I apologize the real problem is that my headset will not display in the audio devices list after sucessfully pairing.

Comment: I've revised your question and title to reflect your last comment.  Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version 14.04 LTS

Comment: It will appear in the audio devices list but only when I run this script "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover"

This is only a temporary fix however.

Comment: It is an appropriate solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/414258/successfully-connected-to-a-bluetooth-speaker-but-how-do-i-direct-sound-there. In case you had not loaded it from your default.pa then put it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using blueman (and it sounds like you do), try [utopic's version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/blueman). Your issue is discussed in [#1283003](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1283003).